# how to load tinymce external plugin

Tags: plugins, tinymce

I'm trying to load external tinymce plugins but no luck so far. I know WordPress offers `mce_external_plugins` filter but it seems not make any difference.

I have `advlist` tinymce plugin inside custom path, and instead of adding it directly inside `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins` directory I'd like WordPress to load it in my `custom/path/to/advlist/plugin.min.js`

**I've tested:**

```
function custom_tinymce_plugins($plugins) {
    $plugins['advlist'] = 'custom/path/to/advlist/plugin.min.js';
    return $plugins;
}
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'custom_tinymce_plugins' );
```

**and:**

```
$customTinymcePlugins = array(
    'advlist' => 'custom/path/to/advlist/plugin.min.js',
);
apply_filters('mce_external_plugins', $customTinymcePlugins);
```

I guess I'm missing something important here but for some reason I can't figure out by myself what it is.

I'm 100% sure that the given URL is correct and the file exist.

Comment: is it for your custom wp_editor or the exists one in wp?